# AmCharts 3 - Remove Listener on first run (reference function inside itself)

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I would like to know how to add a listener that only runs once, I believe in the end this is mostly a generic javascript question, but I might be missing something.

Here's what I have :

```
const listener = chart.addListener('rendered', () => {
    console.log('Chart rendered! This should only print once!');
    doSomethingToChart(chart);
    chart.removeListener(chart, 'rendered', listener);
})
```

The problem here is, is not removing the listener, the console.log is printing on each render. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

`addListener` doesn't have a return value at all, nor makes any mention of one [in the documentation](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#addListener), which is why your code doesn't work. Just store the function reference separately before you add the listner, then call `removeListener` on that reference and it will work, for example:

```
let counter = 0;
const listener = () => {
  console.log('dataUpdated called', counter += 1);
};

chart.addListener('dataUpdated', listener);

let timer = setInterval(() => {
  chart.validateData(); //triggers dataUpdated
  if (counter == 3)  {
    chart.removeListener(chart, 'dataUpdated', listener);
    console.log('dataUpdated removed')
    chart.validateData(); //one more call to confirm that the listner no longer runs
    clearInterval(timer);
  }

}, 1500);
```

Demo:

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "dataProvider": [{
    "country": "USA",
    "visits": 2025
  }, {
    "country": "China",
    "visits": 1882
  }, {
    "country": "Japan",
    "visits": 1809
  }, {
    "country": "Germany",
    "visits": 1322
  }, {
    "country": "UK",
    "visits": 1122
  }, {
    "country": "France",
    "visits": 1114
  }, {
    "country": "India",
    "visits": 984
  }, {
    "country": "Spain",
    "visits": 711
  }, {
    "country": "Netherlands",
    "visits": 665
  }, {
    "country": "Russia",
    "visits": 580
  }, {
    "country": "South Korea",
    "visits": 443
  }, {
    "country": "Canada",
    "visits": 441
  }, {
    "country": "Brazil",
    "visits": 395
  }],
  "graphs": [{
    "fillAlphas": 0.9,
    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "visits"
  }],
  "categoryField": "country"
}, 100);

let counter = 0;
const listener = () => {
  console.log('dataUpdated called', counter += 1);
};

chart.addListener('dataUpdated', listener);

let timer = setInterval(() => {
  chart.validateData(); //this triggers dataUpdated
  if (counter == 3) {
    chart.removeListener(chart, 'dataUpdated', listener);
    console.log('dataUpdated removed')
    chart.validateData(); //confirm that listner isn't called anymore
    clearInterval(timer);
  }

}, 1500);
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>

<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use use the listener like this:

```
const listener = () => {
    console.log('Chart rendered! This should only print once!');
    // ...
    chart.removeListener(chart, 'rendered', listener);
};

chart.addListener('rendered', listener);
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jREaGd) is a codepen showing the behavior.

---

Alternatively you can use an external variable to save the state:

```
let executedOnce = false;
chart.addListener('rendered', () => {
    if (executedOnce) {
      return;
    }
    executedOnce = true;
    console.log('Chart rendered! This should only print once!');
    // ...
});
```

---

Beside that I would recommend switching to [amcharts4](/questions/tagged/amcharts4), because it is much more flexible and has even new chart types. You can migrate easily, beginning with just one chart. You can use amcharts3 and amcharts4 in parallel ([Migration Guide](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/getting-started/migrating-from-v3/)).

In amcharts4 you can subscribe once to an event ([docs](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/event-listeners/)):

```
chart.events.once('datavalidated' => {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work in my case, the init event does not contain the dataProvider loaded and although I wish I can't change to 4.x